# Traverse through json response in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this json response where the is obj.attributes list the following.I want to go through each Object only which inturn has ids..How do i traverse throught the object and print id attribute

```
Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, subject_Keys: "", schoolapplication: Object}
```

I tried

```
for(var item in obj.attributes)
{
     var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
 if(intRegex.test(item)) {
       console.log(obj.attributes[item]["id"]) //This prints undefined
     }
}
```

EDIT1:`console.log(obj)`

```
child {cid: "c33", changed: Object, attributes: Object, _changes: Array[0], _hasComputed: true…}
_changes: Array[0]
_changing: false
_currentAttributes: Object
_hasComputed: true
_pending: false
_previousAttributes: Object
app_id: 8
attributes: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c33"
__proto__: Surrogate
```

console.log(obj.attributes)

```
 Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, subject_Keys: "", schoolapplication: Object}  
 0: Object
   name: "key1"
   schoolapplication: Object
   id: 3
   __proto__: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Could you post the full object and not just `Object` for us to guess what it looks like?

Comment: @Xotic750 What does a javascript object have to do with JSON except for similar syntax? He already uses a JS object.

Comment: @Xotic750 Yet since he said that it prints "undefined" **inside** the loop, you'd think that it actually managed to get through the loop that iterates through `obj.attributes`, hence `obj` **must** be an object and not simply a JSON string (or else it would've failed already there).

Comment: @Hulk: Does your object have a `length` property so that you could treat it like an array? Please also post the exact JSON you are receiving.

Comment: obj.attributes.length is undefined

Comment: Please see the detailed EDIT

Comment: @Hulk: Thanks, I actually meant the JSON string not the object - `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4))` if you want :-)

Comment: @Xotic750 Yeah, but what makes you think that `obj` is an object, but `obj.attributes` is a JSON string? Either he used an object or string - if he knew the difference (which he would if he had two different types), he'd also know how to convert it. Besides, read the OP - he mentioned that `attributes` is of the type `Object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give whole object with data then it would be helpful. But what i have understand i got this solution

```
for(var item in obj)
{
    if(obj[item].hasOwnProperty('id')) {
        console.log(obj[item].id);
    }
}
```